# JSunit usability

Tags: javascript, testing, jsunit

Is JSunit really a direct port of Junit to Javascript? So I have heard, but I am wondering why my company is not using it. My company has lots of smart minds, so If we are not using it I wonder if there are any major issues with Jsunit as a javascript test harness.

Input would be much appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this [jsunit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit)?
Maybe the smart guy's at your company do not even know it exists (actually, learning such things is one of the reasons I read SO). Maybe they haven't yet had the time to evaluate this for real use and deployment, or play with something else.

The tool is not the only thing that is needed to deploy a testing discipline: you need automated test replay, reporting to track deviations and progress, test methodologies, best practices.
You also need documented objectives, and proper training for the teams. that is why in general companies with smart guys do not change tools every time a new tool is around, and sometime do not deploy all best practices immediately.

But in general this does not prevent individuals to deploy them for themselves, try tools, and even succeed to make the whole company evolve and use better processes, eventually building (even) better products.

Comment: yeah, very true. But would you say JSUnit is part of that testing discipline? Does it actually test javascript well?

Comment: I prefer Jasmine's more modern features (BDD like RSpec). We've moved from JSUnit to Jasmine and it's working great for us.

Answer (score 4):

JsUnit is an adaptation of JUnit for Javascript, not a direct port. It's very nice, but is showing its age and is no longer actively developed.

Check out [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine) -- for a modern and actively supported alternative, written by the same people who wrote JsUnit.